# .cache() is not a function Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, pug

I just created a simple backend of Contact form Using Nodejs, Express and Mongoose. I used Pug template engine. I created a backend to take data from users through Contact form and save into my database using Mongoose. But I am getting this following error.

`TypeError: myData.save(...).then(...).cache is not a function`

My `App.js`

```
const express = require("express");
const path = require("path")
const fs = require("fs")
const app = express();
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const bodyparser = require('body-parser')
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/contact', { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true });
const port = 3000;


//define mongoose schema
const contactSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    phone: String,
    age: String,
    email: String,
    gender: String,
    address: String,
});

const Contact = mongoose.model('Contact', contactSchema);


//Express Specific Stuff
app.use('/static', express.static('static'))
app.use(express.urlencoded())


//Set the template Engine as Pug
app.set('view engine', 'pug')
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'))//Set the views directory


//Endpoints
app.get("/", (req, res) => {
    res.status(200).render(`index.pug`)
})

app.post('/', (req, res) => {
    var myData = new Contact(req.body);
    myData.save().then(()=>{
        res.send("This Data has been saved")
    }).cache(()=>{
        res.status(400).send("Item was not saved into DB")
    })    
})


app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`The application started succefully ${port}`)

});
```

My `index.pug`

```
doctype html

head
  meta(charset='UTF-8')
  meta(http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible' content='IE=edge')
  meta(name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0')
  title Contact
  style.
    @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Baloo+Tammudu+2&display=swap');
    * {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: 'Baloo Tammudu 2', cursive;
    }
    .contact {
    max-width: 60%;
    /* text-align: center; */
    /* display: flex;*/
    position: relative;
    left: 20%;
    align-items: center;
    }
    input{
    height: 40px;
    font-size: 15px;
    padding: 7px 5px;
    }
    textarea{
    font-size: 15px;
    padding: 7px 5px;
    }
    form{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    }
    .btn{
    background-color: black;
    max-width: 70px;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
    }
    button{
    margin: 10px;
    padding-top: 5px;
    }
    h1{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center ;
    }
    button a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
    }
.contact
  form(action='/' method='post')
    h1 Membership Form
    label(for='name') Full Name
    input#name(type='text' name='name' placeholder='Enter your name')
    label(for='age') Age
    input#age(type='number' name='age' placeholder='Enter your age')
    label(for='email') Email
    input#email(type='email' name='email' placeholder='Enter your Email Id')
    label(for='gender') Gender
    input#gender(type='text' name='gender' placeholder='Enter your Gender')
    label(for='address') Address
    textarea#address(name='address' cols='30' rows='05' placeholder='Enter your Address')
    button.btn Submit
```

I just created a simple backend of Contact form Using Nodejs, Express and Mongoose. I used Pug template engine. I created a backend to take data from users through Contact form and save into my database using Mongoose. But I am getting this following error.
Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using catch not cache.

For extra context catch is a method available on promises to catch errors that are thrown or promises rejected.

Cache is terminology to save temporary data to help with performance etc.